# How to speed up the processing when using remote database shared server in an WinForms application?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, performance, remote-access

I want to develop a Windows Form application for my website which uses a shared database server. The website works nicely and fast. But when I try to access the server from application, it is taking lot of time. I used the same database functions as of my website. So how can I make my application work with approximate same speed as of my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a local cache for your database. There are a lot of ways you can do this. Accessing the database via internet will always be slower that a local cache.

Comment: sorry typo, that's what I meant

Comment: how to achieve this in C#? Even if user of the app doesn't have database server installed

Comment: If you are using sql look at the [embedded database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345108/how-to-embed-attach-sql-database-into-visual-c) files. Other solutions would be to use a client database like sqlite

Comment: But whenever some new content is posted on my site, I want that to appear on app too at the same time. So if I check the connection to remote server first and then if not available then I will go for cache but it will still take time. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: use the cache first and get the updates on a background thread. This way the user has something to work with while you are getting the update. It would also be nice to inform the user that you are updating with a progress bar or something like that

Comment: thanks DjSol. I will have a try on it.

Comment: @ShivaPareek how did that work for you and how can I do it? can you help me out in that